# How do I create a new email from R (and optionally attach a file)?

Tags: r, email

Oftentimes, when I finish some analysis in R and RStudio, I'd like to email a data frame to a colleague. Right now, my workflow involves writing the data frame to csv, then opening my email client, creating a new email, attaching the csv and sending the email.

I'd like to be able to use a function in R that was something like:

```
sendemail( object = df , to = mybuddy@hisaddress.com, subject = 'my analysis')
```

Ideally, when I ran that function, it would attach the object `df` as a csv and open an new email in my default email client.

I looked at the packages `sendmailR` and `mailR`, but they both seem to be focused on using R directly via SMTP. I'm looking for something more interactive--I want to be able to write and edit the body of the email within my email client, not at the R console.

I also considered something like `browseURL("mailto:mybuddy@hisaddress.com")`. Unfortunately, while mailto links seem to work in my browser, calling the same mailto address via `browseURL()` didn't open an email (I'm way out of my depth trying to figure out if that's a problem unique to my machine or not).

The option to attach an object as a csv is ideal, but not a hard requirement.

Suggestions/advice?

Comment: it sounds like the only thing you want out of the function is to create your csv and fill out your subject/recipient address. then you would finish the email in your email app

Comment: But I want the function to actually open the new email for me, the way a mailto: URL would do. I'll probably build in some sane defaults (ie. the email address of the guy I'm always sending stuff to). Not a huge deal, but it'd certainly make things more efficient!

Comment: If I specifically call out the location of Firefox in my call to `browseURL()`, I can get a new email to open: `browserURL("mailto:foo@bar.com", browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe")`. However, I can't seem to write a mailto link that adds an attachment from a local location.